# Is there a way to convert .so using the new ELF ABI to the old

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, debian, abi

I build a product on a recent Ubuntu version and pack an executable and a shared lib.

```
3.2.0-48-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 6 19:43:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

My .so `file` return :

```
ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

When I unpack and try my product on an old debian (2.6.26-2-amd64 ... Now 2010 ... x86_64) I got the following error :

```
ELF file OS ABI Invalid
```

I picked the info `file` of a .so I found on that old debian and get:

```
 ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

Is there a tool to convert a binary from the new ABI `version 1 (GNU/Linux)` to the old `SYSV`  ? Or which is the best options to be able to deliver product for both system (Debian 5 / Debian 12) ?

Comment: Sine you are building the product, you have the source code. Just recompile it on the old system! (Perhaps, use a `chroot`-ed environment for the old distribution under the new one).

Comment: Thanks for your advice, We finally start the setup of a build node (in our build farm) for that old Debian version... Take some times but seems to be the only correct way to solve that issue (for production system)!